# how to print multiple values from a foor loop in karate

Tags: karate

I have a json which looks like this..

```
{
"name": "xyz.json",
"fileSize": "391 B",
"timestamp": "2020-06-22 12:03:00 GMT",
"tag": "abc1"
},
{
"name": "abc.json",
"fileSize": "391 B",
"timestamp": "2020-06-22 12:03:01 GMT",
"tag": "abc2"
},
```

i have 755 records like above in a json. Now for getting the timestamp from the above json i have written.

```
* def myfun2 = 
"""
function(arg){
           
return arg[754].timestamp;
}
}
            
"""
* def numos = call myfun2 data
Then print 'numos--',numos
```

This prints the last timestamp from the json.

Now i have tried some thing like this to print all the 754 timestamp values..

```
* def myfun2 = 
        
"""
function(arg){
           
for(i = 0; i <= arg.length; i++)
{
return arg[i].timestamp;

}
}
"""
* def numos = call myfun2 data
Then print 'numos--',numos
```

It still prints 1 value and not all the 754 values. I am pretty sure i am making  a mistake somewhere. Can anyone help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the recommended way to do loops: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

```
karate.forEach(items, function(x){ karate.log('item is', x) })
```